# New to SQL - Trouble getting quarterly date output

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sqlbulkcopy, sql-insert

I'm really new to sql and databases in general.  Trying to teach myself the language but I'm stuck and would like to know what's wrong. So here's what I have:

```
1976-01-01,6.1
1976-04-01,5.7
1976-07-01,5.7
1976-10-01,5.8
```

...

And I'm inserting it into a table

```
CREATE TABLE "va unem"
    (Date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Val REAL   
);
```

``

```
COPY "va unem"
    FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\SQL\fred\vsaur.csv'
    DELIMITER ',' 
    CSV
;
```

This works. The problem is that when I `select *`, the output truncates the date. eg:

```
1|1976|6.1
2|1976|5.7
3|1976|5.7
4|1976|5.8
...
```

I need each quarter to show.  This does not give me each quarter.  Help appreciated.  I'm using postgresql. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Where did the first column in the `select *` result come from if the table really looks like that? You may want to post your _real_ schema :)

Comment: Sorry, the 1, 2, 3, 4, is not actually part of the output...postgres numbers each row. I wanted to upload a screenshot but I apparently lack the repute.

Comment: Ok, the reason I figured it wasn't the schema was also that the output for the date field looks very strange, almost like it imported it into an int column. Got nothing more, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that you have the BD format must match the format that has the CSV file. Executing the following command in the console Postgesql:

```
SHOW datestyle;
```

Should return:

```
  dateStyle
-----------
  ISO, YMD
(1 row)
```

But it returns to modify the formatting is done with the following command:

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, YMD";
```

That Postgest version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys - really appreciate it. 

Looks like the datestyle was the problem. I changed it to YMD and works fine.  

Not exactly sure what version I'm using. Downloaded the latest windows option. program called "pgadmin III".